# Scala and Akka HTTP: How to get the entity content as string

Tags: scala, httprequest, httpresponse, akka-stream, akka-http

I am very new to Akka HTTP so please accept my apologies beforehand for the very elementary question.

In the following piece of code, I want to retrieve the entity from the HTTP request (entity will be plain text), get the text out of the entity, and return it as a response.

```
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer
  import system.dispatcher

  val requestHandler: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = Flow[HttpRequest].map {
    case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, Uri.Path("/api"), _, entity, _) =>
      val entityAsText = ... // <- get entity content as text

      HttpResponse(
        StatusCodes.OK,
        entity = HttpEntity(
          ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,
          entityAsText
        )
      )
  }

  Http().bindAndHandle(requestHandler, "localhost", 8080)
```

How can I get the string content of the entity?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any specific reason by you aren't using Akka HTTP scaladsl for building routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to call [`toStrict`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.11/akka/http/scaladsl/model/RequestEntity.html#toStrict(timeout:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)(implicitfm:akka.stream.Materializer):scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Strict]) on the `RequestEntity`, which loads the entity into memory, and [`mapAsync`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html#mapasync) on the `Flow`:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val requestHandler: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = Flow[HttpRequest].mapAsync(1) {
  case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/api"), _, entity, _) =>
    val entityAsText: Future[String] = entity.toStrict(1 second).map(_.data.utf8String)

    entityAsText.map { text =>
      HttpResponse(
        StatusCodes.OK,
        entity = HttpEntity(
          ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,
          text
        )
      )
    }
}
```

Adjust the timeout on the former and the parallelism level on the latter as needed.

Comment: Jeffrey, many thanks for your great response! By mistake, I had `GET` in my original example, which I have now fixed. Feel free to edit your solution, too (I wasn't allowed to suggest an edit myself).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to use the already Unmarshaller which is in scope (most likely it will be the `akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.PredefinedFromEntityUnmarshallers#stringUnmarshaller`):

```scala
val entityAsText: Future[String] = Unmarshal(entity).to[String]
```

This approach ensures the consistent usage of the provided Unmarshaller for String and you wouldn't have to cope with timeouts.